# Breakpoint on delete[] when destroying char *

Tags: c++, memory, breakpoints, operator-keyword

I'm doing an assignment for class in which I can't use the string class. I need to use char* as arrays and doing arithmetic with them.

My code being executed in main is the following: I create 2 myString objects and I add them. Then this is done correctly. Both strings get concatenated. but, there's a breakpoint at `delete[] str`. Can you tell me where I do wrong exactly? I'd like to understand what happens.

```
myString& myString :: operator+ (const myString& s)
{


    myString tmp;       //myString temporal
    strcpy_s(tmp.str, strlen(str)+1,str); //STR is copied to tmp.str

    Alloc(strlen(s.str)+size+1);        //Then memory is allocated for both    values



    strcpy_s(str, strlen(tmp.str)+1, tmp.str); //WE COPY TMP.STR INTO STR   NOW WITH ENOUGH SIZE FOR THE NEXT...

    strcat_s(str, strlen(s.str) + size+1, s.str);   //..ARGUMENT WE CONCATENATE 2 MYSTRING.STR

    return (*this);


}
```

This is the class myString

```
class myString
{
public:
//Propietats
int size;
char* str;


//CONSTRUCTORS
myString();


myString(const myString&);


//myString(myString&);


myString(const char*, ...);


//Utilities
int Len(char*);
const void Clear();
const void Alloc(const int);


//Operators
bool operator== (const myString&) const;



bool operator== (const char* s) const;



const myString& operator= (myString&);



const myString& operator= (const char* s);



bool operator!= (const myString&) const;


bool operator!= (const char* s) const;


myString& operator+ (const myString&);


myString& operator+ (const char*);





//Metodes

    ~myString()
    {
        delete[] str; // **ERROR** THERE'S A BREAKPOINT HERE
    }
};

#endif
```

My error is that there's a breakpoint in delete[] str; And I don't know what to do. It means there's an overflow? How do I solve it? 
I'm quite new to pointer arithmetic so don't be harsh.

Comment: Are you sure "breakpoint" is a proper word here? Is usually means intended stop during debugging.

Comment: "In software development, a breakpoint is an intentional stopping or pausing place in a program, put in place for debugging purposes. It is also sometimes simply referred to as a pause."

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakpoint

Comment: it says. 2DEngine.exe has triggered a breakpoint

Comment: you're corrupting memory, save yourself and use std::string

Comment: i know but i didn't set that breakpoint up. it happens during execution

Comment: it's an assignment. I'm actually creating my own string class

Comment: Use appverifer or valgrind to find where you read/write out of bounds/invalid memory, also why not store the length of the buffer in the class

Comment: Here's a guess. Ruben is using a tool (e.g. MS VS) that has a 'first chance' exception handling. When he means is his program has performed an illegal operation and the debugger has 'caught it in the act'. Ruben, if that's the case can you tell use the full message it displays? You should 'break' program execution and look at the call stack. It's usually a cinch to see precisely what has gone sour.

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2013 and i get this message.
  ntdll.dll!_RtlpBreakPointHeap@4() Unknown
  ntdll.dll!_RtlpCheckBusyBlockTail@8() Unknown
  ntdll.dll!_RtlpValidateHeapEntry@12() Unknown
  ntdll.dll!_RtlValidateHeap@12() Unknown
  KernelBase.dll!_HeapValidate@12() Unknown
  msvcr120d.dll!__CrtIsValidHeapPointer() Unknown
  msvcr120d.dll!__free_dbg_nolock() Unknown
  msvcr120d.dll!__free_dbg() Unknown

Comment: You got a message as well. It's probably access violation or overwrite. Anyway the answers below are right. You don't appear to allocate space to `tmp` before copying to it. BTW: The whole semantic of that method looks wrong. You're implementing the binary `+` operator which is normally defined to return a new string that is the ordered concatenation of `*this` and `s` (if you consider that concatenation). In fact you appear to be attempting `+=` which would append `s` to `*this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably corrupting the heap.

```
myString tmp;
```

What is tmp.str after this instruction ? Is tmp.str a NULL pointer ? A pointer to a buffer with some default size ?

```
strcpy_s(tmp.str, strlen(str)+1,str);
```

Did you make sure tmp.str has room for strlen(str)+1 char ? 
You probably should call `tmp.Alloc(strlen(str)+1)` before this instruction.

Comment: I did call tmp.Alloc and changed Alloc method. I now pass a reference to alloc and it allocates the length you said into the str of the object.

Comment: What do you mean by "pass a reference to alloc" ? Does it work now ?

Comment: It worked!!!!! Thank you internet buddies! I've been tweaking it, adding a 1 here and 1 there printing the things and finally it's working. I guess so bug prone but will try to fix that.. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
myString& myString :: operator+ (const myString& s)
{
    myString tmp;       //myString temporal
    tmp.Alloc(strlen(str)+1);  // Add this line
    strcpy_s(tmp.str, strlen(str)+1,str); //STR is copied to tmp.str
    ...
```

You are not allocating room in `tmp` string. Once allocated, it should work fine.

Comment: I'm using an Alloc method:
const void myString :: Alloc(const int i)
{
 if (str != NULL)
 {
  delete[] str;
  str = new char[i];
 }
 
   }

Comment: @Ruben, what if str == NULL ? You don't modify it ? The code you gave looks bogus.

Comment: @RubenIdigora You are using Alloc method on `this` object and you should do it also on `tmp`.